# Is there a way to use SVG animation based on SMIL in React Native?

Tags: react-native, animation, svg, svg-animate, smil

I'm writing a mobile application using React Native, and we have a bunch of nice animations done in SVG, by using so-called SMIL commands inside this SVG(tags like "animate" etc).

I was trying to find a way to use those animations but to my knowledge none of the libraries that I was able to find(including react-native-svg, react-native-svg-animations) able to do that. 
I also checked this link: https://react-svgr.com/playground/?native=true which claim to transform SVG code to JSX, and it said that:

```
"/* SVGR has dropped some elements not supported by react-native-svg: style, animate */"
```

Is there anyone who was able to find efficient way to run these animations on React Native? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is [fakesmile](https://leunen.me/fakesmile/faq.html) a possibility?

Comment: it seems javascript that supposed to run in web browser, not a react-native environment. unfortunately

Comment: I am sniffing around the same problem, I have SVG with <animate> tags inside. I would need to load it inside React Native. Did you find solution?

Comment: yes use library @svgator/react-native and pass SVG image as a string to it