# React Native showing animated SVG

Tags: react-native, svg

I have an animated SVG image:-

http://test.impossible-creations.com.hk/crown.svg

when viewing it at chrome browser, it animates well.

However, when I try to import it to my react native project (e.g. by [react-native-svg](https://github.com/react-native-svg/react-native-svg)), although it can display the svg image, it did not animate.

This is the way that I imported the svg:-

```
import { SvgUri } from 'react-native-svg';

<SvgUri
    width="85%"
    height="85%"
    uri="http://test.impossible-creations.com.hk/crown.svg"
/>
```

Actually is displaying animated SVG possible in React Native? If yes, what is the proper way to do so?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60405580/is-there-a-way-to-use-svg-animation-based-on-smil-in-react-native

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [lottie](https://github.com/lottie-react-native/lottie-react-native)

You will need to export your svg animation as a json with a bodymovin plugin.